# Predict the probability of someone leaving based on two conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics, probability

I am currently working on a dataset that provides information over several years about employees at a big company. Information includes whether or not the employee quit that year (True or False for every year), what Tax Bracket they're in and what age they are. Based on the dataset, I have plottet the percentage of people quitting against their age, and the percetange of people quitting against their tax bracket. Assuming those numbers can be considered as the probability of someone quitting given their age, and the probability of someone quitting given their tax bracket, I would like to find a way to predict the probability of someone quitting given both age and tax bracket.

I cannot use our dataset for that, because it is too small and most combinations do not occur in it (so I simply get 0% for everything). Is there a way to predict it, using some kind of model?

Comment: This sounds like a math problem, which has nothing to do with python per se

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sounds like a math problem, and perhaps belongs to math stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

A direct and simple approach would be to use the mean of the percentage you get from the age and tax bracket that they are in. The downsides is that you consider that both those variables are independant and have the same weight in deciding wether an employee will quit or not.

A better approach would be to use a classifier to give you a more accurate prediction of the probability of the employee quitting based on his tax bracket and age. You could start with common classifiers like Random Forest.